# Nop generation in the C# lock statement

Tags: c#, locking

I was just reading an article by Eric Lippert http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix/

For the following code, he mentions that the compiler could generate a no-op instruction between the monitor enter and the try-protected region:

```
var temp = obj;
Monitor.Enter(temp);
try { body }
finally { Monitor.Exit(temp); }
```

Why would the compiler generate a nop there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a problem with the legacy x64 jitter.  It uses NOP instructions to *align* code.  Aligning code is an optimization strategy, it makes the branch predictor more efficient and reduces the work the instruction decoder has to do to reach the branch target.  You can see this back in the Intel Processor manual titled "Intel 64 and IA-32
Architectures
Optimization Reference Manual" chapter 3.4.1.5:

> Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 12. (M impact, H generality) All branch
>   targets should be 16-byte aligned.

Sadly, these NOPs are now a possible target for Thread.Abort(), allowing the thread to be aborted before the try/finally block is reached.  With the unhappy outcome that the lock will be taken but not released.  Very low odds this happens, not zero.

This is not the complete story, afaik it was just a plain bug in the jitter since the try block is not a branch target in practice.  The legacy x64 jitter team had some other gritty problems, looked like their members scattered after the job was done and known bugs were not getting fixed.  Microsoft created a new team and they rewrote the jitter, project name RyuJIT and available since .NET 4.6.  They discarded the x64 codebase and used the x86 jitter codebase as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

nop instructions are there for putting breakpoints in non optimized build.

nop instruction is generated just in debug mode when we are running non-optimized build, if we build project with optimization flag on then these instruction will not be in the generated IL.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "putting breakpoints"? Who puts breakpoints where?

Comment: I think what you mean to say is the compiler will emit NOP instructions for lines that don’t have any actual IL associated with them but which you might want to put a breakpoint on. Found this on http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2004/02/03/what-does-optimize-do/